# Question about notation from Dineen's Multivariate Calculus and Geometry

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I'm referring specifically to the third (2014) edition, a preview of which can be found on Google books (which also happens to contain the passage I'm asking about)

The notation that I'm having difficulty with is the following sentence (slightly paraphrased from page 6)

Fix $X \in \mathbb{R}^n$. If $e_i \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $g_i(x) = X + xe_i$ for $x \in \mathbb{R}$ then $g_i$ is differentiable and $g_i'(x) = [g_i'(x)](e_1) = e_i$ at all $x \in \mathbb{R}$

Specifically, what does $[g_i'(x)](e_1)$ mean in this context? I understand everything else here and can derive the result without problems. In fact, if that middle equality was omitted then I wouldn't have a problem at all.

Later on he repeats the notation when talking about directional derivatives, namely

If $v \in \mathbb{R}^n$ then the function $G:x \in \mathbb{R} \to X + xv \in \mathbb{R}^n$ is differentiable at any $X \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and, as above, $G'(x) = G'(x)(e_1) = v$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$

Again, it's the $G'(x)(e_1)$ that I'm not following.

My best guess at the moment is that he's using $e_1$ to denote the single basis vector in $\mathbb{R}$ and then trivially using it to extract the first column from $G'(x)$ (which is an $n \times 1$ matrix in this context, and so only has a single column) but this seems so absurd that I'm surely wrong

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: The derivative of a vector mapping is a linear transformation (ie, a matrix), so my guess would be the notation $G'(x)(e_1)$ is meant to refer to the matrix G' being multiplied by/applied to the vector e1

Comment: Well yes that's what I thought, but I still don't see the purpose of it, what is it supposed to demonstrate?